# Loads normal locally but not correctly when i publish

Tags: javascript, json, html, audio

I am tryint to create a little RadioPlayer that works online . Now this is the JavaScript Code that i have

```
function changeLink(link)
{
/* this changes the link and plays the radio*/
var radio= document.getElementById("radio");
radio.src = link;
radio.play();

}

function jsonLoad()
{
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "playList.txt";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          readJSON(myArr);
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

   }

function readJSON(obj)
{
    var list = "<ui>";
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length ; i++) 
  {
      list += "<li><a href='javascript:changeLink(" +"\"" + obj[i].radioLink + "\"" +");'>" + obj[i].name + "</a></li>";
     }
  list += "</ui>";

  document.getElementById("radioLoad").innerHTML = list;
}
```

Also this is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> My Radio Player</title>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body onload="jsonLoad()">

    <p>This is the link that i will change his property</p>
    <audio id="radio" src="#" controls autoplay preload="auto" ></audio>


    </audio>
    <br>
    <p id="radioLoad"> 

    </p> 




</body>
```

Things is that locally the JSON File is perfectly working, and the webpage shows as i expected. When i put it on a server though, it's like the JSON file is not loaded and the other fuction  (readJSON(myArr);) is not fired. Seems that there is something wrong with the IF Condition but i don't know excatly why. Can somebody help me?

EDIT: Seems that the code only works locally in Google Chrome. In internet explorer the links are generated but they don't play the radio when i click on them. Also on the iphone simulator that i tested, the audio tag is not working properly. I will try on different webbrowsers also.

EDIT2: it works now. I managed to figure outthe issue. It was nothing wrong with the code, it was with the server i was hosting on. So i changed the web hoster and now it works. You can see it here: 
http://radioplay4all.16mb.com/

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if it helps. i am using WebMatrix to create my website and publish it

Answer (score 2):

Without debugging it myself I can't be sure, but I'm pretty sure that your problem is in your `readJSON()` function, when you try to get the `.length` property of an object (JSON.parse() returns a javascript object), since objects don't have a `.length` property. To find the number of keys an object has, you could use `Object.keys(myArr).length`. So in your for loop, `obj.length` is Null, so `i` can't be less than Null, so it doesn't execute. So if you replace `i < obj.length` with `i < Object.keys(obj).length` that should fix the problem.

Comment: How come i don't have this issue locally and this happens on the server? i don't get it   EDIT: I tried your idea though, works locally but still not working on the server. I also noticed that the code Might Only work in google chrome.

Comment: Firefox 3.5
Internet Explorer 8
Chrome
Opera 10
Safari 4

Comment: Those are the web browsers that support JSON.parse(). Still wouldn't explain it working locally but not on the server. I will try to get you an answer.